# Use semver package to determine if version matches

Tags: node.js, npm, semantic-versioning, npm-cache

Say I have this in the .npm cache:

```
lodash/
  1.2.4/
  1.3.3/
  2.11.2/
```

What I want to do is read the directories in the lodash folder and see if any of the versions are acceptable.

Say I am looking for this version:

```
"lodash":"^2.11.1"
```

or

```
"lodash":"~2.11.1"
```

How can I compared the versions in the cache with the desired version, to see if a version in the cache, satisfies it?

This is what I have right now:

```
'use strict';

import semver = require('semver');
import async = require('async');
import * as cp from 'child_process';
import * as fs from 'fs';
import * as path from 'path';

export const cacheHas = function (getCacheLocation: string, dep: string, version: string, cb: any) {

  const dir = path.resolve(getCacheLocation + '/' + dep);

  fs.readdir(dir, function (err, items) {

    if (err) {
      return cb(err);
    }

    const matches = items.some(function (v) {
      return semver.eq(v, version);
    });

    return cb(null, matches);

  });

};
```

so I am simply using `semver.eq()`....so my question is, is there a better call to use other than `semver.eq()`?

Comment: Is this what you're looking for? `satisfies(version, range)`: Return true if the version satisfies the range.

Comment: Yeah probably, so `range` is the one with the `~` or `^` and `version` is a strict version right?

Comment: Feel free to add an answer with some basic tests and I will accept thanks

Comment: @ZachB care to add an answer? I think your idea is correct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `semver` package has a `satisfies` function that does exactly that:

```
semver.satisfies(v, version)
```

(where `v` is what you've got in your cache, and `version` is the range you want to test if `v` satisfies)